# Data storage using pointer of 'struct'

Tags: c++11

```
struct arraystack
{
int top; 
int b;
int *c;
};
arraystack* s;
s->c[++s->top]=20;
```

How can we use pointer c as an array to put data in that??

Comment: You don't provide nearly enough information to help with this. You already seem to know how to use an array (`s->c[++s->top]`) and you don't explain what `top` or `b` are. You should probably try and provide an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate memory. So you have to know how many elements you will store at maximum.

```
s->c = new int[nb_elements]
```

If you don't know, you can allocate a certain amount of elements, and use `realloc` to increase size of array when it is full.

Also instead of using raw array,  you should use vector

```
struct 
{
    ...
    std::vector<int> c;
}
```

Comment: question is tagged as c++, so why the malloc instead of new?

Comment: Good question... I'm answering questions on C side of site and I forget c++ tag... I edit